# In C#, what is the fastest way to remove one collection from another Collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have two collections that are both:

```
 List<MyObject>
```

1. fullCollection
2. oldCollection

I want to find out which objects are in the full list but not the other list.  What is the fastest ways to do something like this:

```
var inOneButNotTheOther = 
    fullCollection.Remove(oldCollection, new MyObjectComparer());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fullCollection.Except(oldCollection, new MyObjectComparer())
```